# Count unique id separeted by commas in single row

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following details in MySQL as

```
   user_id                  follow_user_id                                                    
   1                      2,3,3,3,3
   5                      1,2,3,3,3,3
   6                      1,2,3,3,3,3
```

i write the following code to get the unique code as follow:

```
SELECT LENGTH( follow_user_id ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( follow_user_id, ',', '' ) ) +1 AS no_of_follow FROM follow WHERE user_id =1;
```

But it provide the result:6
I need exactly unique rows: i.e:4

Comment: Bad DB design you should consider normalization and one row for each user_id and follow_user_id

Comment: there is only one row but i does not know how to correctly post

Comment: ok Abhik Chakraborty  sir i properly post it

Comment: This will be very difficult if not impossible using the query. If you want to keep this structure you need to do the calculation using PHP once you select the data.

Comment: i solved this problem by the help of hello code $query="SELECT follow_user_id FROM follow WHERE user_id ='".$data['user_id']."' "; $query_run=mysql_query($query); $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run); $count= count(array_unique(explode(",",$row['follow_user_id']))); echo $count;

Comment: I would still suggest you to normalize the data since later you will have difficulties while try to find some relational data using query.

Comment: Once upon a time, a programmer thought to himself, "Hey, I will save myself some time by using a comma separated list in a single field, all I have to do is split the values!" And he lived happily, ever after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from DB design questions you could use in PHP after fetching the row to $result:

```
count(array_unique(explode(",",$result["follow_user_id")));
```

Comment: thanks sir  some minor change count(array_unique(explode(",",$result['follow_user_id'])));

Comment: $query="SELECT follow_user_id FROM follow WHERE user_id ='".$data['user_id']."' ";
            $query_run=mysql_query($query);
            $row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);
          
            $count= count(array_unique(explode(",",$row['follow_user_id']))); echo $count

Answer (score 1):

$query="SELECT follow_user_id FROM follow WHERE user_id ='".$_POST['user_id']."' "; $query_run=mysql_query($query); $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);

$count= count(array_unique(explode(",",$row['follow_user_id'])));

$count;

Answer (score 0):

This is better and faster ;)

```
count(array_flip(explode(",", $result["follow_user_id")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or doing it in SQL:-

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(follow_user_id, ',', units.i + tens.i * 10), ',', -1) AS col1)
FROM sometable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)units
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)tens
WHERE user_id = 1
```

(copes with up to 100 comma separated values).

But this would be so much easier with a properly normalised database design